# tkinter widget calling a method from another widget

Tags: python, tkinter

Whilst working on a tkinter application (Tcl/Tk 8.6 and Python 3.9.2) I recently encountered an error that I was able to resolve, but I think the existence of the error highlights some gaps in my knowledge and potential weaknesses in my approach.

A reproducible example of the error is below - this code will not work and returns the error `AttributeError: 'parent_class' object has no attribute 'first'`.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class child_one(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.x = 10

    def print_x(self):
        print(self.x)

class child_two(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.b = ttk.Button(self, text='Button 1',
                            command=parent.first.print_x).grid()

class parent_class(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.grid()

        self.second = child_two(self)
        self.first = child_one(self)

        self.first.grid()
        self.second.grid()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    w = parent_class(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

However the code will work if I reverse the order in which the instances of `child_one` and `child_two` are created i.e. replacing

```
        self.second = child_two(self)
        self.first = child_one(self)
```

with

```
        self.first = child_one(self)
        self.second = child_two(self)
```

in the definition of `parent_class`.

I'd really appreciate any explanations or link to resources to help me understand the program flow which causes this to happen - it appears to me that when I create `w` and get to the line `self.second = child_two(self)` Python is just looking at the part of the instance of `parent_class` which has already been created, and not the whole definition of the class.

Would this happen if this was not the first instance of `parent_class` to be created? Is it specific to tkinter? (I was only able to create a simple reproducible example with tkinter widgets, not with classes more generally.)

I suppose another solution would be to make `print_x` a (static?) method of `parent_class`? I also assume there's not enough detail here to definitively state if that (or alternative structures) would be preferable to facilitate interface between the components of my application, but would be interested to hear any suggestions for good practices in this space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no mystery here. If you do `self.first = child_one(self)` first, it defines `self.first`. When you then call `child_two(self)`, it is able to access `parent.first` since it was previously created.

However, if you call `child_two(self)` first, at that point in time `parent.first` doesn't exist. Thus, when you do `command=parent.first.print_x`, `parent.first` doesn't exist.

> it appears to me that when I create w and get to the line self.second = child_two(self) Python is just looking at the part of the instance of parent_class which has already been created

That is correct. You can't reference things that haven't been created yet.

> Would this happen if this was not the first instance of parent_class to be created? Is it specific to tkinter?

I'm not quite sure what you're asking in the first part of that question. It will always happen if you try to reference any object attribute before that attribute has been created. And no, this isn't specific to tkinter. It's a fundamental aspect of the way that python works.

This is a good example of why it's generally best to create proper functions rather than using `lambda`. `lambda` is good when you need to pass arguments, but you don't need to do that in this case. Even then, a proper function is better than directly referencing some other object *at the time the button is defined*. An arguably better way would be to use a function so that `self.parent.first` doesn't need to be resolved until you actually click the button.

For example:

```
class child_two(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.b = ttk.Button(self, text='Button 1', command=self.print_x)
        self.b.grid()

    def print_x(self):
        self.parent.first.print_x()
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan - when laid out so clearly (as you have done) it does seem obvious!

Answer (score 1):

When you say *"Python is just looking at the part of the instance of parent_class which has already been created, and not **the whole definition of the class**"*, you seem to be expecting python to have built a static description of your class before the program starts running.

Python does not work that way, it's a dynamic language. As Bryan just said, the `first` variable is created only when you assign to it for the first.